# Javascript html add onclick to a tag element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I want to add this to a link.

```
onclick="javascript:window.location='mailto:?subject=Interesting information&body=I thought you might find this information interesting: ' + window.location;"
```

So it gives

```
<a id="email" href="#" onclick="javascript:window.location='mailto:?subject=Interesting information&body=I thought you might find this information interesting: ' + window.location;">Email</a>
```

I tried something like :

```
 $("#email").find("a").onclick = function () {
        javascript:window.location= 'mailto:?subject=Interesting information&body=I thought you might find this information interesting: ' + window.location;
    }
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: `$("#email").find("a").click(function() { location.href = 'mailto:?subject=Interesting information&body=I thought you might find this information interesting: ' + window.location'; });` Something like this.. Read about [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) handler.

Comment: A simple web search for *"jQuery click"* would turn up lots of results on how to do it properly

Comment: If @GGo's post answered your question please mark it as answered by clicking the green tick under his answer. This will award both of you some points and let other see that his answer matched your question :-)

Comment: You're combining **jQuery** with **DOM**:  although `onclick` property is deprecated and you should use `addEventListener` method, it makes part of **DOM**, whereas you're using **jQuery**, so you should try with `click` method or, more generically, `on` method and specify `"click"` as event name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` event is deprecated. Try this instead :

```
$("a#email").click(function () {
    window.location.href = 'mailto:?subject=Interesting information&body=I thought you might find this information interesting: ' + window.location.href;
}
```